# Getting bullets

Tags: html, css

Want to get a bullet in html/cs (three of them actually) on the bottom of my page. I tried to do sth like this:

```
<style>
    div.container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 200px;
        font-family: cursive;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class='container'>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

But I guess that it isn't the best idea to code it this way. Now it is possible that my dots are covered by other html elements (just because of the fact that div is out of normal flow as an absolutely positioned element).

So my question is how to do it properly (and without using divs with border-radious: 100% set in their CSS). In fact I'd be glad to see a solution using dot signs (.). Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: so don't position it absolute, put it in a container div after the the previous content (also in the container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're after " • • • " ?

Use:

```
&bull;
```

Depending upon your chosen Doctype, you may need to use:

```
&#149;
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution using dot signs (.)

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BE8v/)**

```
<style>
    div.bullets {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 200px;
        font-family: cursive;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>some content</div>
      <div class='bullets'>...</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Edit**

I guess you could us a negative margin then `margin-top: -170px;`

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BE8v/2/)**

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. Space between dots and the content above them is too large (and setting div's height to - let's say - 50px doesn't help).